# How can I get fullcalendar to pass a start date dynamically to a new event via a function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

In the month view, I click on the date, and then the view changes to the day view. When I click on the new event link, I would like the start date to be that of the day selected instead of the default of today's date.

If today is March 12, 2013, and I want to create an event on March 28,2013, I'll click on the day cell for March 28 in the month view. The day view for March 28 will come up. I will click the new event, and the start time for the event will be March 12, 2013 (whatever current day is, is shown) and I'll need to manually select March 28, 2013 (or whatever day I want).

I figured out the way to hard-code it, but this isn't going to work in production. Is there a way to dynamically pass the selected days's start date so that it's automatically set for any day of month is selected?

Here's the dayClick code:

```
        dayClick: (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) ->
          if (allDay)
          # clicked entire day
            $('#calendar')
              .fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay')
              .fullCalendar('gotoDate', date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate())
```

do I use the select method? if so how? I don't understand the doc http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/select_method/
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/select_callback/

In the events.js.coffee, I'm attempting to dynamically create a new event link in the :

```
     $('#new-event').append("<a>custom link built thru js</a>").attr('href', 'events/new?starts_at=2013-03-28') <-- How to set starts_at by obtaining the date from day selected dynamically? Use calendar's select method to obtain the date parameters?
```

How are the parameters for the selected date from dayClick passed in? Or do I obtain this info from the gotoDate?

EventsController.rb:

```
     # GET /events/new
     # GET /events/new.json
     def new
       @event = Event.new
       @event.starts_at = (params[:starts_at]) # sets the date
       respond_to do |format|
         format.html # new.html.erb
         format.json { render :json => @event }
       end
     end
```

Event.rb model:

```
      def as_json(options = {})
        {
         :id => self.id,
         :title => self.title,
         :description => self.description || "",
         :start => starts_at,
         :end => ends_at,
         :allDay => self.all_day,
         :recurring => false,
         :url => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.event_path(id),
         :type_of => self.type_of
        }
      end
```

views/calendar/show.html.erb:

```
    <%= link_to "new event", controller: "events", 
                     action: "new",
                     starts_at: "28-03-2013" %> This will set the starts_at param manually via Rails. How do I obtain this dynamically? Using jQuery see code above in  to create link that has the starts_at parameter (see code above).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but here's how I got it to work. In the events.js.coffee:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar
      dayClick:  (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) ->
        if (allDay)
        # clicked entire day
        $('#calendar')
          .fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay')
          .fullCalendar('gotoDate', date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate())
          $('#new-event').append("<a>custom link built thru js</a>").attr( 'href', 'events/new?starts_at=' + date )
```

Comment: Do you have a fiddle for this?